# Gradle dependencies for Jupyter notebook

Tags: java, gradle, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm writing Java code in a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) via [IJava](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava) . I want to add external dependencies such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). Using [gradle](https://gradle.org/), this would normally be incorporated in the build.gradle file via the line

`compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.3.2'`

How can I add dependencies at runtime via gradle in the Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the `maven` magic for this. Since the [dependency is on maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/4.3.2), it is as easy as adding `%maven com.opencsv:opencsv:4.3.2` in a cell.

For example

```java
%maven com.opencsv:opencsv:4.3.2
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
// ...
```

The name `maven` is slightly misleading as Maven (or Gradle) is a build tool rather than strictly a dependency manager, but as the dependencies are often resolved from the Maven Central repository the notion of adding a "maven dependency" was a good enough metaphor.

Comment: Thanks! Can I add dependencies from my own Gradle projects?